# Automaper how to map this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I tried to do this

```
public class TaskTableViewModel
{
    public string CourseCoursePermissionsBackgroundColor { get; set; }
}

 public class Course
{
    public virtual IList<CoursePermission> CoursePermissions { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        CoursePermissions = new List<CoursePermission>();
    }
}

    public class CoursePermission
{
    public virtual string BackgroundColor { get; set; }

}
```

So I am trying to get BackgroundColor into the viewModel but I can't figure it out as it is in a list.

```
List<Task> tasks = taskService.GetAllTasks("email@gmail.com");

    List<TaskTableViewModel> viewModel = new List<TaskTableViewModel>();
    List<TaskTableViewModel> taskViewModelList = new List<TaskTableViewModel>();

    viewModel = Mapper.Map<List<Task>, List<TaskTableViewModel>>(tasks);
```

This is what I am trying to do.

```
  taskViewModelList[i].CourseCoursePermissionsBackgroundColor = tasks[i].Course.CoursePermissions.BackgroundColor
```

the above would get me the access to the color. So in the end Task and taskTableViewModel should have the same number in each collection.

Comment: The `Course.CoursePermission` need an index like `Course.CoursePermission[0]` for it to make sense to me. Can you explain how that index should be?

Comment: @svrist - Ya I guess I might need a index there(and it should be zero). I am trying to figure out how to tell automapper this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Task,TaskTableViewModel>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.CourseCoursePermissionsBackgroundColor,
                         opt => opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Course.CoursePermissions[0].BackgroundColor));
```

And then try the Mapper.Map you have

Comment: hmm...I guess that's the way it has to be done. I mean I don't like that the index is hardcoded zero but maybe I have some design flaw(I am not very good with db structure). Either way I do it I guess I would have the zero index.

Comment: I wouldnt know. You are trying to map a list of something to a single field. You have to chose either which of the list elements you want, or map the list to another list

Comment: You could perhaps use something like `src.Course.CoursePermission.Any()?src.Course.CoursePermission.First().BackgroundColor:SomeDefaultColor`